# Partition alert message when using Boot Camp Assistant: "The startup disk cannot be partitioned or restored to a single partition."

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I have a 13" Early-2015 MBP Retina in which I am trying to install Windows 8.1 on. When I went into bootcamp, I received the ever so common error of:
[image]

When I went to the newly designed disk utility, it told me I had 2 partitions. Of course, I knew this couldn't be true, so i went into terminal and typed diskutil list and got:

```
bash-3.2# diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh SSD           81.0 GB    disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:                  Apple_HFS Data                    39.3 GB    disk0s4
/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh SSD          +80.6 GB    disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 9839618F-7659-4E0C-BF5C-48B0C94D5E37
                                 Unencrypted
```

I want to know:

1. Which partition to delete
2. How to delete it in a (preferably safe) way that would make my hard
   disk "clean" of everything but my main Macintosh HD partition

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to delete the *Data* partition. disk1 (Macintosh SSD) is no real partition/disk but a virtual volume residing in disk0s2 but containing your system.

1. Backup the content of *Data*
2. Open Disk Utility
3. Choose the superior disk and hit "Partition":

   [image]
4. Click on the *Data* partition and hit the <kbd>-</kbd> button:

   [image]
5. Click <kbd>Apply</kbd>

   The Data partition will be removed, the Recovery HD moved to the end of the disk and Macintosh SSD will be expanded:

   ```
   diskutil list #before
   /dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
      #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
      0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *68.7 GB    disk0
      1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
      2:          Apple_CoreStorage System                  51.2 GB    disk0s2
      3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
      4:                  Apple_HFS Data                    16.5 GB    disk0s4
   /dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
      #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
      0:                  Apple_HFS System                 +50.9 GB    disk1
                                    Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                    4AACDE41-E3A1-444A-A5F6-C1491F46149E
                                    Unencrypted
   diskutil list #after
   /dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
      #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
      0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *68.7 GB    disk0
      1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
      2:          Apple_CoreStorage System                  67.9 GB    disk0s2
      3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   /dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
      #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
      0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh SSD          +67.5 GB    disk1
                                    Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                    4AACDE41-E3A1-444A-A5F6-C1491F46149E
                                    Unencrypted
   ```