# Remove partition failed - the partition is gone, but now there is missing space. How do I get it back?

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I was trying to get rid of an old Bootcamp partition I didn't want anymore. I followed [these instructions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/239988/partition-alert-message-when-using-boot-camp-assistant-the-startup-disk-cannot) to remove a partition using Disk Utility, but the removal failed. Now the partition is gone, but the space it used to occupy hasn't been merged back to the main disk partition - it's just *gone*. My SSD is 1 TB, but Macintosh HD is only 775 GB, the same as it used to be.

What happened to this extra space and how can I get it back? And why did it leave me in this weird half-removed position instead of removing the partition properly?

Here's what my Disk Utility looks like now:

[image]

Here's what comes up when I enter "diskutil list":

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       
IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            774.7 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       
IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +774.3 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 8679E121-03C8-47B0-844E-961A437E5CA5
                                 Unencrypted
```

Comment: I think you should be able to use the partition button on "Macintosh HD" to re-claim the lost space. Unfortunately I'm not 100% sure and don't have the possibility to test it at this time. Perhaps someone else could confirm this?

Comment: @Jules [Here's what I see when I do that](http://i.imgur.com/EeRAfTX.png)

Not sure how to reclaim the space this way because it's not seeing that extra space.

Comment: Can you show us the info given when you type the command `diskutil list` in Terminal?

Comment: @paper1111 Sure, added to the original post.

Comment: @JM My answer to the question linked in your post is an answer to a different kind of problem. You should always delete a *BOOTCAMP* partition with the Boot Camp Assistant.

Answer (score 1):

- Backup your main volume.
- Open Terminal.app
- Check the file system integrity of your main partition: `diskutil verifyVolume disk0s2`
- If everything is fine, expand your logical volume group (and the inherent logical volume):

  ```
  diskutil cs resizeStack lvUUID size
  ```

  In your case that's:

  ```
  diskutil cs resizeStack 8679E121-03C8-47B0-844E-961A437E5CA5 0g
  ```

  If you run Sierra the magic size 0g may fail and you have to enter a distinctive size:

  ```
  diskutil cs resizeStack 8679E121-03C8-47B0-844E-961A437E5CA5 999300m
  ```

  If you get an error like: *Error: -69771: The target disk is too small for this operation* choose a slightly smaller size like 999200m until you are successful.
- If you get a different type of error, the whole (previous) Disk Utility operation failed and corrupted the internal structure of the LVG. You have to restore the main volume from your Time Machine backup then.